# Android Preferences seem to be ignoring setDefaultValue

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm building an Android application and I have preferences stored in classes loaded from the web (we sync preferences with a website) however using a PreferenceScreen, they seem to get ignored when using the correct APIs.

In XML I have turned off persistence and I make sure in Java like so `p.setPersistent(false);`

then I set the default value `p.setDefaultValue( boolean );`

I use only EditTextPreferences and CheckBoxPreferences, and both these don't work. I've tried setting it in the Editor, but it doesn't seem to work.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally managed to do it. Thanks to the extremely clever people at Google, they made this incredibly difficult as preferences seem to only be set at design time (bit silly).

I made an interface called `FlushPreferences` which implemented a method similar to setDefault, and made subclasses of the preference classes I was using `EditTextPreference` and `CheckBoxPreference` which they called the `onSetDefaultValue` internal function getting them to show up properly.

Code: https://gist.github.com/1430073

(P.S Anybody who sees this at Google: Please fix it for Android 4.1 or something)

Comment: You run a better chance of getting this fixed in Android 4.1 if you do it yourself. Write a bug report, followed by your fix. See http://source.android.com/source/life-of-a-patch.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this! :D (However, I'm targeting 2.2+)